# Variables with respect to DOM

Tags: javascript, string, dom, variables

This is surely a JS beginner question.

My issue is I want to use the value of the variable `type` to access the relevant checkbox; however it is treating the variable as a string. I have tried it to two ways.

```
function toggleGroup(type) {
    if (document.getElementById(type).checked == true){
        alert("foo");
    }
}
```

or

```
function toggleGroup(type) {
    if (document.nav.type.checked == true){
        alert("foo");           
    }
}
```

Comment: indeed. 'foo', for one, is a choice of the most sophisticated minds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have no way of knowing how type should be treated - you haven't show us how the function is being called (in particular, we don't know what you are passing as its argument).

If it *is* a string (matching the id of an element), than `document.getElementById(type).checked` should work (although `== true` is redundant).

`document.nav.type.checked` should not work, because dot-notation property names are not interpolated. You have to use [square bracket notation](http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/js-dot-notation/) for that: `document.forms.nav.elements[type].checked`. This will match on name or id - if you have multiple elements with the same name, then `document.forms.nav.elements[type]` will be an object you can treat as an array (and won't have a checked property).

Answer (score -1):

you can as well compare with "true"

Comment: Comparing with the string "true" would just require additional type conversion, make the code less clear, and imply that you could compare a false value with the string "false" and get a match.

Comment: oh, you need to use the getAttribute() method on the DOM element to use the string form "true".

Comment: If a checked attribute is set on an element, then its value must be "checked", not "true" (browser bugs not withstanding)